# Entrar numa tela com a opção do dropdown já selecionada

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

Tenho essa dropdown

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Grupo de Desconto", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("GrupoDescontos", new SelectList(ViewBag.Desconto, "Id", "Descricao"), new { @id = "GrupoDescontos", @class = "Makewide" })
            @*@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HomeTemplateId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })*@
        </div>
    </div>
```

Sempre que seleciono um ID na tela de lista e quando entro na tela Detalhe, a opção de ID=1 é que fica selecionada, mesmo que eu tenha selecionado a oção 3, por exemplo. Como faço para deixar selecionado na Dropdown o item do ID correspondente?

**EDIT1**

Esse é o cshtml com a dropdown list que é chamada pela index e depois pela Dropdown

```
<div>
    <h4></h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Grupo de Desconto", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("GrupoDescontos", new SelectList(ViewBag.Desconto, "Id", "Descricao"), new { @id = "GrupoDescontos", @class = "Makewide" })
            @*@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HomeTemplateId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })*@
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<div id="GridPartial"></div>

@Html.Partial("DetailsPartial")

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#GrupoDescontos").change(function () {
            $.ajax
            ({
                url: '' + $(this).val(),
                type: 'GET',
                    success: function (dados) {
                    $("#GridPartial").empty();
                    $("#GridPartial").html(dados);
                    //var resultado = dados;
                },
                    error: function (erro) {

                        alert("erro");

                }
            });
        });
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#GrupoDescontos").val();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Como não havia o cshtml antes eu fiz um exemplo colocando o jquery para executar em um $( document ).ready, mas você está usando ajax, se é após a chamada dele que quer alteração você pode fazer a chamada no success do ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar um JQuery simples, assim:

```
$("#GrupoDescontos").val("Valor_a_Selecionar");
```

Se trouxer esse valor de uma `ViewBag`:

```
$("#GrupoDescontos").val('@ViewBag.Valor_a_Selecionar');
```

Veja um exemplo abaixo:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#MeuDropDownList").val("2");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="MeuDropDownList">
  <option value="0">Selecione...</option>
  <option value="1">Azul</option>
  <option value="2">Vermelho</option>
  <option value="3">Verde</option>
</select>
```

**Com C# na Controller**

Se preferir pode fazer com o `Selected` do `SelectListItem`:

```
List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem> {
    new SelectListItem() { Text = "Selecione", Value = "0" },
    new SelectListItem() { Text = "Azul", Value = "1" },
    new SelectListItem() { Text = "Vermelho", Value = "2", Selected = true },
    new SelectListItem() { Text = "Verde", Value = "3" }
};
```

Comment: O val() no seu exemplo está fixo, como eu passaria um val() dinâmico de acordo com o item selecionado?

Comment: Pode ser pela model, pode ser um viewbag... se você monta seu select list na controller pode nela mesmo já setar qual valor vem selecionado.

Comment: Mas como eu pegaria esse valor e jogaria dentro da jquery?

Comment: @pnet atualizei a resposta com mais um exemplo

Comment: Uma ViewBag dentro do val() do jquery comigo dá erro

Comment: @pnet os exemplo que dei você vai precisar usar no success do seu ajax, selecionando o valor após a conclusão do ajax pois ele está atualizando a GridPartial com o retorno do Ajax... vc tbm pode fazer na controller que o ajax faz a chamada para não ser necessário fazer mais uma lógica no success...

Comment: Só falta limpar a DIV e posso ir pra casa contente